# JavaScript keypress Enter is fired for Japanese IME on FireFox, but not on Edge

Tags: javascript, html, cjk, ime

I have tried [the W3 Schools example code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_trigger_button_enter.asp) for handling the enter key for input text. I copied the source code from that site's page and pasted below.

The problem is that on FireFox, if I press the enter key to finish Japanese input mode, the code is also triggered. On Edge, it did not. Is this a FireFox bug, or just a different behaviour? Anyway, how can I circumvent this?

[image]

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: What about the [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)? Does that work better?

Comment: @SebastianSimon This is strange. When I clicked "Try it yourself" to change the event, a new editor window opened, and I tried the same thing without changing the event, and this problem did not happen there. It somehow only happens in the tutorial page. I tried to check if the script used is exactly the same as the editor, but the tutorial page's HTML was long and complex, so I could not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use KeyDown event. KeyPress is reporting every keycode from keyboard. Some keys on keyboard are not only putting one keycode but multiple keycodes. KeyDown event should pack all keycode from one actual pressed key into one event.

KeyPress is meant to do more low level approach

Comment: Didn’t notice this in the question at first, but now that you point it out: the [`keypress` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) is deprecated. It shouldn’t be used at all.

Comment: Ow, @SebastianSimon now you got point from me. I didn't noticed it earlier either. Great catch, thanks. I can imagine why they made it deprecated.